# How to integrate a Photoshop design in WordPress?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, magento

I've first to design a layout and then to develop this design in WordPress website. I've read some posts on this but can't make myself clear, hence asking here:

1. To design the layout, can I do like any other normal website or is there any WordPress specific design structure which will need to follow?
2. Once I finish designing the layout, what would I do?

a. I'll write my own HTML/CSS for created design as I do in case of other normal website? If yes, what would I do next after this?

or

b. I'll have to get a theme downloaded from net which is developed for WordPress, and then (after installing) I'll edit its HTML/CSS pages to convert it into my design (This is what I think right now). If yes, wouldn't be the downloaded theme have code and design elements which would not require for my created design. Also what if my design has something which is not there into theme?

I'm confused how should I proceed with design to development in order to make my work go in right direction. Please excuse me if my questions are really basic, I've not yet worked on any WordPress, Joomla or Magento things.

Comment: c. You can hire freelancer and let him do that.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do in wordpress whatever you can do with a standard website.

The only difference is that you'll have to stick to some standard HTML structure.

Start by reading the [templating documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Templates)

Then you can download a [minimal theme](http://torquemag.io/starter-themes/) to get a base to start from.